# Многопоточная передача файлов по FTP

Tags: linux, ftp, kde, filezilla

люди!
Filezilla передает данные на ftp в несколько потоков, в то время как файловые менеджеры linux типа Dolphin, Krusader, и тд. передают файлы по одному.
Это как то связано с настройками системы, но не могу понять где это делается и как (KDE), потому что разные файл-менеджеры ведут себя одинаково.
Вопрос: как настроить многопоточную передачу файлов в Linux (KDE)?

Comment: Это просто особенность клиентов. Для простых ФМ'ов общего назначения, где ftp реализован на уровне «чтоб работало» ни какой специальной настройки для этого почти наверняка нет. Если подобная функциональность строго необходима можешь использовать какой-нить специализированный клиент, например, ту же filezilla...

Comment: `man lftp`. Должно помочь. (@Fat-Zer, JFYI)